# Sorting function for queues

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue

Is there a way to define a "sorting" function depending on the priority in ActiveMQ (or any other queuing system)? I know I can set a priority number and that messages with higher priority will be sent before, but I would like to define a function so that I can compare the messages that are already waiting with the new one.

Something like a compareTo function that activeMQ will use to define which is the next message.

I need to take into account several parameters and depending on the time and the length of the message, the priority might change over time.

Is there a way to do this? I have not been able to find info about this online, but I guess this is quite a common problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

haven't seen any way to do this w/o dequeing/requeueing messages...based on your use case, you might be able to use the [camel resequencer](http://camel.apache.org/resequencer.html) to consume in batches and reorder as you go (or populate another queue, etc)